# Different printable representation in Spyder Ipython vs Python prompt

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder

Spyder version: 5.0.1, Ipython kernel version: 3.9.5

Python version: 3.9.5

```
class A: 
    pass
x = A()
```

In Python prompt, the result is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEfjx.png):

```
>>> x
<__main__.A object at 0x00000202BC5293D0>
>>> print(x)
<__main__.A object at 0x00000202BC5293D0>
>>> repr(x)
'<__main__.A object at 0x00000202BC5293D0>'
```

But in Spyder Ipython, the result is [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj1vf.png):

```
In [3]: x
Out[3]: <__main__.A at 0x1d5d9519130>

In [4]: print(x)
<__main__.A object at 0x000001D5D9519130>

In [5]: repr(x)
Out[5]: '<__main__.A object at 0x000001D5D9519130>'
```

My question:

Why the `Out [3]` in Spyder Ipython is `<__main__.A at 0x1d5d9519130>` instead of `<__main__.A object at 0x000001D5D9519130>`? I think they should be the same other than two quotation marks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry for my expression. My question is about the difference of ```x``` and ```repr(x)``` in Spyder Ipython. I think they should be the same other than two quatation marks.

Comment: ahhh I see. The IPython REPL does all sorts of special things to pretty-print objects.  it is the same number, just formatted differently.

Comment: Formatting could be different it's just it one is not using 'object' keyword!

Comment: Plain `ipython` (without Spyder) gives the same id display all 3 ways.  It's a good idea to include a `__repr__` method to avoid confusion like this.